# Hw to store Objects in Node.js Buffer?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to store object in Buffer? The only option I see for now is to store response from `JSON.stringify({})`

code like this:

```js
const objectBuffer = Buffer.from({id:123})
```

Throws an error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the Node.js platform official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_from_object_offsetorencoding_length) states:

> Static method: Buffer.from(object[, offsetOrEncoding[, length]])#
>
> Added in: v8.2.0 object  An object supporting
> Symbol.toPrimitive or valueOf(). offsetOrEncoding  | 
> A byte-offset or encoding. length  A length.

The object being passed as the first argument needs to either support `Symbol.toPrimitive` or `valueOf()`. Here down a basic example copied from the documentation:

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

class Foo {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive]() { // the symbol converting the object to the primitive value and used by the `Buffer` under the hood
    return 'this is a test';
  }
}

const buf = Buffer.from(new Foo(), 'utf8');
// Prints: <Buffer 74 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 61 20 74 65 73 74>
```

The common used alternative is `stringify`ing the object as you did and passing the `string` result to the static variant `Buffer.from(string[, encoding])`.